# I am attempting to implement user login and authentication. I do not know where to begin with authentication and protecting the users information

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I am working on a side project where the user can create, update and delete notes. I have the notes part of this project working, now I am hoping to add user functionality. This is the first time I am implementing such features. I have begun by creating a schema for the user:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Please enter your name!"]
    },
    email:{
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Please enter your e-mail!"],
        unique: true
    },
    password:{
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Please enter a password!"]
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.models.User || mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

I have also created a basic API which GET's and POST's to a collection in my database:

```
import dbConnect from '../../../utils/dbConnect';
import User from '../../../models/User';

dbConnect();

export default async (req, res) => {
    const { method } = req;

    switch (method) {
        case 'GET':
            try {
                const user = await User.find({});

                res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: user })
            } catch (error) {
                res.status(400).json({ success: false });
            }
            break;
        case 'POST':
            try {
                const user = await User.create(req.body);

                res.status(201).json({ success: true, data: user })
            } catch (error) {
                res.status(400).json({ success: false });
            }
            break;
        default:
            res.status(400).json({ success: false });
            break;
    }
}
```

After this, I spend a few days attempting to implement authentication and login features but keep failing. I cannot get past the login and registration part, let alone authentication and logout. If anyone could help it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

first of all don't worry about not knowing how to implement login/authentication, those subjects can be a real pain in the ass. Because of this I highly suggest to not reinvent the wheel. There are plenty of example on the internet which will help and teach you how to implement this properly. You will learn the good patterns by doing these thing over and over again in applications.

I suggest looking at this blog for now: https://hoangvvo.com/blog/full-fledged-app-with-next-js-and-mongodb-part-1/.

Goodluck.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I will look at the blog and attempt to implement those features into my project.